# IIS Rewrite rule to redirect and remove query string

Tags: iis, rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite in IIS 7.5 from an old website to the new one. We have a list of URL's with and without query strings.

I can get the URL's without query strings to redirect but not **with**.

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps.config" />
    <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{StaticRedirects:{URL}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

this is the sample rewritemap:

- add `key="/boat-insurance/canoe.aspx" value="/boat/canoe-insurance"` (this works)
- add `key="/boat-insurance/canoe/details.aspx?#details" value="/boat/canoe-insurance"` (this does not)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to rewrite based on the query string (everything behind the `?`) but the `#details` is NOT part of the query string. It's what is called the fragment identifier and it's a client-only part of the URL. The browser never sends that to the server so it's impossible for the server to use that for URL rewriting.

Comment: Thanks Marco, i could get the query string part to rewrite but the #details part was driving me up the wall !! Thanks for the pointer.